# How to create a class method with name from string?

Tags: javascript, oop

Is this possible to have a class in JS and declare 2 method names from string?
I mean something like this:

```
function MyClass()
{
var methods = ['hello', 'hey'];
for (var i in methods)
{
    this[methods[i]] = function()
    {
       alert('This is method ' + methods[i]);
    }
}
}
```

This should create me a class with function hello and hey. I need to create a few functions which have very similar body but different names.
I don't want to use eval, so the code can be compiled.

Comment: This is possible and its already working for you. What is your question then?

Comment: @RahilWazir Thank you, sorry I forgot to add 'new' and had: `var c = MyClass();` It is indeed working with `new MyClass`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
function generator(i) {
    return function (x) {
        return x * i;
    }
}
function foo(methods) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        this[methods[i]] = generator(i);
    }
}

var test = new foo(['nulify', 'repeat', 'double']);
console.log(test.nulify(10));
console.log(test.repeat(10));
console.log(test.double(10));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

More questions...